# iTextPDF html2pdf problem with special characters

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem with special polish characters like "Ś Ą Ż Ć" in html to pdf using iTextPDF html2pdf library. I checked and the file test.html is encoded in UTF-8.
My version:

```
implementation group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'html2pdf', version: '5.0.1'
```

My code is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String baseUri = "test.html";
        String dest = "output.pdf";

        try {
            FileInputStream htmlFile = new FileInputStream(baseUri);
            byte[] html = htmlFile.readAllBytes();
            createPdf(html, dest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createPdf(byte[] html, String dest) throws IOException {
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, true, true);
        fontProvider.addFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN, PdfEncodings.UTF8);
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);


        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(html), pdf, properties);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        Wiśniewski This is an example<br />
        Gżegżółka This is an example<br />
        Ząbek This is an example<br />
        Ä (ä) - Ä umlaut     Ö (ö) - Ö umlaut     Ü (ü) - Ü umlaut     ß (eszett) - Scharfes S This is an example<br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but a pdf result is:
[PDF RESULT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Ov8.png)

why? It is the problem with polish characters but for instance with German characters isn't.
Thank you in advance.

**//EDIT**

***IT WORKS!***

I had to download a font with these special characters like Polish and many others.

```
package org.example;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgram;
import com.itextpdf.io.font.FontProgramFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.font.FontProvider;

import java.io.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String baseUri = "test.html";
        String dest = "output.pdf";

        try {
            FileInputStream htmlFile = new FileInputStream(baseUri);
            byte[] html = htmlFile.readAllBytes();
            createPdf(html, dest);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createPdf(byte[] html, String dest) throws IOException {

        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
        FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont("times.ttf");
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram);
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(html), pdf, properties);

        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i am also facing this issue, can you please share the fonts you have downloaded or links to fonts.